# Numbers of solutions of the equation $\log_3\frac {2x^2+3x+3}{5} = \frac {1}{\log_{2x^2+3x+9}9}$

Tags: logarithms

Pretty straightforward question. When I solved it, I got two positive and two negative solutions, so that would make 4 in total. None get discarded as the arguments in the logarithm still stay positive.

However, the solution is supposed to be 2, so I'm not sure where I went wrong.

I got the values of $x$ as $-2$, $1/2$, $12/5$ and $-18/5$

Comment: Are you sure you have the right base for the log on the right hand side?

Comment: Yes. This is not really a problem, you invert the logarithm (whatever that rule is called, basically but it to a base 9) and then $9$ is $3^2$ and after a bit of fiddling you get the same bases on both sides.

Comment: Agreed.    So your equation is really  $2\ln(2x^3+3x+3) = 5\ln(2x^2+3x+9)$

Comment: Hm, I didn't really get that, how'd you get the five out of the log? What I got, if $t=2x^2+3x+3$, is $\frac t5 = \frac {t+6}{9}$. I didn't fiddle with natural logarithms, their specifics aren't really what I should use in this problem given the level of knowledge assumed for this exercise.

Comment: The $\frac 15$ is inside the logarithm on the LHS, how'd you get it out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23670/discussion-between-john-doe-and-matt-biesecker).

Comment: My Bad.  $\log_3(t/5) = \frac{1}{2} \log_3( t+ 6),$ which leads to $(t/5)^2 = (t+6).$  So $t=30$ or $t=-5.$

Comment: Yup. Which when solved gives two solutions. And each one of them gives two more for the quadratic equation that $t$ represents. So that's 4 solutions, but the my book says the right answer is 2. Is this simply a mistake on their part?

Comment: Reject $t=-5.$    But I get two solutions for $x$ (3 and -9/2)$ (And confirmed with MAPLE).    Either we looked at the wrong equation or your book is wrong.

Comment: Right, $t$ can't be negative. That's where I got it wrong (apart from calculating the solutions wrong). Thanks a lot! How can I give you your due points if you didn't write an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the change of base formula: $$ log_a{x}={\log_b{x}\over\log_b{a}}$$
Remove the polynomial from the base of the log on the right by changing the base to 3